# Haar trained data set for gesture recognition - Counting

Tags: xml, opencv, dataset, haar-wavelet

I have been trying to find a HAAR trained data set (OpenCV/C++) that is used to perform counting using hand fingers. I did find a lot for trained data set for hand recognition but so far not for finger counting. Is there a well known resource?

Any links are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

haar, or any other of those cascades are binary, yes-no classifiers.

you can ask them: "is it a hand with 2 fingers ?", but not: "how many ?".

to abuse them for finger counting, you would have to train one cascade for each pose, and later test your candidate image against each of them seperately.

so, not a good idea, i would say.

(and it might explain, why you don't find any on the net)

Comment: Oh well i hoped someone did it for free so that a lazy guy like me could use it :)